# Android: always launch top activity when clicked on notification

Tags: android, android-activity, notifications

**EDIT**: please note: i completely re-explained my question.

I have application with two `Activites`: **A** and **B**. `Activity` **A** is `MAIN`. So, application starts, and **A** appears on the screen. User press the button on it, and new `Activity` **B** appears on the screen.

So, there's now 2 activities in my "back stack": **A** and **B**.

Now I press "Home" key, and then click on my app's icon on launcher: `Activity` **B** appears on the screen (**not A**), as far as it is top activity in my task.

Now question: how can i make `Intent` to similarly open the currently **top `Activity`** of my task?

I need it to use in `Notification`: when user clicks on my `Notification`, top `Activity` of this task should appear on the screen, not a specified one.

I tried many Intent flags, such as `SINGLE_TOP` and others, but i still can't get what i need.

Does anyone know the solution?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Well, after spending several hours some days, i found the solution:

```
Intent notificationIntent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
notificationIntent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_MAIN);
notificationIntent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_LAUNCHER);
notificationIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_RESET_TASK_IF_NEEDED);
```

That's the way which launcher starts applications, and it works nice for notification Intent too.

Answer (score 1):

I used like this.

```
private void notifyUser(Context context) {

    notificationManager = (NotificationManager) context
            .getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
    CharSequence text = "Test Notification";
    Notification notification = new Notification(R.drawable.icon, text,
            System.currentTimeMillis());

    Intent resultIntent = new Intent(context, StartActivity.class);
    resultIntent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_MAIN);
    resultIntent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_LAUNCHER);
    resultIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK
            | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_RESET_TASK_IF_NEEDED);

    TaskStackBuilder stackBuilder = TaskStackBuilder.create(context);
    // Adds the back stack for the Intent (but not the Intent itself)
    stackBuilder.addParentStack(GeneralSettingsActivity.class);
    // Adds the Intent that starts the Activity to the top of the stack
    stackBuilder.addNextIntent(resultIntent);
    PendingIntent resultPendingIntent = stackBuilder.getPendingIntent(0,
            PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

    notification.flags = Notification.FLAG_AUTO_CANCEL;
    notification.setLatestEventInfo(context, "Title", text,
            resultPendingIntent);
    notificationManager.notify(AUTOSYNC_COMPLETED_NOTIFICATION,
            notification);

}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use android:launchMode="singleInstance".
May this will working.

Comment: no, of course i tried it, but it does not work as i need it to work (look my scenario)